# Edit button does not show up in Internet Explorer

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using an MVC 3 razor grid with version 2011.2.712.340 of the Telerik extensions.

I have an Edit command button in my html for the grid. The edit button shows up in Chrome & Firefox, but not Internet Explorer with the same exact code base.

Would someone be able to tell me what I need to do in order to get it to display in IE?

Actually, in additon to the Button not showing up, the data for the record is shifted over starting in the Command column....

Also, this only happens in IE9. If i put the browser in IE9 compatability mode or IE8 or IE7, the page renders fine.

What do I need to do for it to render properly using IE9?

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to Hidden Columns in Telerik, have a look at this post for the workaround:

http://www.macaalay.com/2011/09/29/telerik-mvc-grid-workaround-for-not-rendering-properly-in-internet-explorer/